# react-router: 'Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: {HelloWorld}', while the component is right there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and am trying to get up to speed with react-router (v1.0.0).

I've setup a simple component and a simple route, but it's giving me an error: `Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: {HelloWorld}`. You'd think it to be a clear error, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

Here it is:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>Hello world</p>
        );
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component="{HelloWorld}"/>
    </Router>
);

ReactDom.render(routes, document.querySelector('#main'));
```

If I switch out `routes` with `<HelloWorld />` in the `ReactDom.render` statement, it works fine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the documentation again, you will see that `component` expects a reference to a component, not a string:

```
component={HelloWorld}
//        ^          ^
```

In JSX attribute values, `"..."` represents a string (just like in JavaScript), and `{...}` represents an arbitrary JavaScript expression. Hence `"{HelloWorld}"` is very different from `{HelloWorld}`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and solving my problem! Funny how you can overlook such things a gazillion times...

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my morning.